# phpMyAdmin is not accessible on centos 7 after instal

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, centos7

I'm running:

- Centos 7
- PHP version 7.3
- Apache/2.4.39
- mysqlnd 5.0.12
- phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-3.el7.noarch

after installing phpmyadmin it gives me this error `File not found.` when I try to visit http://my.server.ip.address/phpmyadmin/

I have added the following to httpd.conf

```
Include conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

Before adding the line above it would give me 404 error.

I removed phpmyadmin and reinstalled but nothing changed.

Here is the conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf code:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       # Require ip 127.0.0.1
       # Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     # Allow from 127.0.0.1
     # Allow from ::1
     Require all granted
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       # Require ip 127.0.0.1
       # Require ip ::1
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     # Allow from 127.0.0.1
     # Allow from ::1
     Require all granted
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```